# Opening Excel in wxpython

Tags: c++, python, excel, wxpython, wxwidgets

Can I open excel spreadsheet as a reponse to event in wxpython? I want to build an application which entails the neccessity to interact with excel in visual mode? Is this possible? Can somebody provide me a brief example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
xl = DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = 1
xl.Workbooks.Open("somefile.xls")
xl.Save("somefile.xls")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use win32com as Adam mentioned or you can use os.startfile or you could even use the subprocess module. The last two are more generic and are covered in this tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/04/python-101-how-to-open-a-file-or-program/